# Does the integral $\int_{2}^{+ \infty} \frac{\arctan(e^x)\sin3x}{\sqrt{\ln(x)}}dx$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider the improper integral
>   $$\int_{2}^{+ \infty}  \frac{\arctan(e^x)\sin3x}{\sqrt{\ln(x)}}dx.$$
>   Does it converge?

**My work**. We have that:
$$0 \leq  \frac{\arctan(e^x)\sin3x}{\sqrt{\ln(x)}} \leq \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\ln(x)}}$$

Except that $ \int_{2}^{+ \infty}\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\ln(x)}} = + \infty $ which is not helpful.

How can I show if the integral converges or not? Thank you.

Comment: Edited your post - please check that this is what you meant.

Comment: @nbubis Yes, it is what I meant.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, when $x>0$, $arctan(x) > 0$ and $sin(x) > 0$.

Comment: @nbubis $arctan(e^x)$ instead of $arctan(x)$. I have just seen it.

Comment: @Jacob. - Is that OK now?

Comment: @nbubis I have just edited it.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes, you're right. I will have $-  \int_{2}^{+ \infty }\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\ln(x)}} = - \infty $ and $ -  \int_{2}^{+ \infty }\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\ln(x)}} \leq \int_{2}^{+ \infty}  \frac{\arctan(e^x)\sin3x}{\sqrt{\ln(x)}}dx $ Which will not answer the question. Am I right?

Comment: Conditionally convergent by Dirichlet's test.

Comment: @Jacob. Your inequality is incorrect, because $\sin (3x) <0$ a lot of the time.

Comment: @zhw. You're right. I did not pay attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral converges. Let $h(x)=\frac{\arctan(e^x)}{\sqrt{\ln(x)}}$ then, by taking the derivative, we see that $h'(x)<0$ as soon as
$$2\ln(t)t<\arctan(e^t)(e^{-t}+e^{t})$$
which holds eventually as $t\to +\infty$. Hence $h$ is strictly decreasing to zero in $[a,+\infty)$ for some $a\geq 2$. 
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{+ \infty}  h(x)\sin (3x) dx&=\frac{1}{3}\int_{a}^{+ \infty}  h(x) d(-\cos(3x))\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\left[-h(x)\cos(3x)\right]_a^{+\infty}+\frac{1}{3}\int_{a}^{+ \infty}  h'(x) \cos(3x) dx\\
&=\frac{1}{3}h(a)\cos(6)+\frac{1}{3}\int_{a}^{+ \infty}  h'(x) \cos(3x) dx.
\end{align*}
Moreover, last integral is absolutely convergent because $h'<0$ and
$$\int_{a}^{+ \infty} | h'(x) \cos(3x)| dx\leq \int_{a}^{+ \infty} | h'(x) | dx=- \int_{a}^{+ \infty}  h'(x)  dx=-\left[h(x)\right]_a^{+\infty}=h(a)<+\infty.$$
Since $\int_{2}^{a}  h(x)\sin (3x) dx$ is finite, it follows that $\int_{2}^{+ \infty}  h(x)\sin (3x) dx$ is convergent.

Comment: @Jacob You are welcome!

Comment: Why is $h$ decreasing?

Comment: @zwh Good point. I edited my answer with a proof that $h$ is eventually decreasing (which is sufficient for convergence). With a little effort one can show that $h$ decresing in $[2,+\infty)$.